# Add space between multiple citations in authoryear-style

Tags: biblatex

I use `biblatex` with the `authoryear-icomp` style and want to cite two works of the same author that were written in the same year. The current output of `\citet{examplea, exampleb}` is

*John (1991a,b)*

but I would prefer to add an additional space resulting in

*John (1991a, b)*.

I already tried to redefine `\multicitedelim` and `\compcitedelim` via

```
\renewcommand{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
\renewcommand{\compcitedelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
```

but that did not have the desired effect.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib, style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@MISC{examplea,
  author = {John, Doe},
  title = {MyBook A},
  date = {1991}
}
@MISC{exampleb,
  author = {John, Doe},
  title = {MyBook B},
  date = {1991}
}    
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\citet{examplea, exampleb}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you try redefining them? That is, did you use the macros biblatex supplies such as \addspace etc.?

Comment: @cfr, I did use biblatex macros, see the edited question

Comment: I can reproduce it without natbib compatibility and with authoryear-comp as well as authoryear-icomp. I don't seem to be able to change that delimiter at all - I tried changing it to e.g. X just to test and get no effect. If I don't use authoryear, I can change the delimiter but that seems to be it. I take it the compcitedelim is the one which is meant to get changed? But I tried changing multicitedelim and textcitedelim as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The culprit of this behavior is the bibmacro `textcite`...

Adding the following lines in the preamble (package `xpatch` is needed)

```
\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
  {\setunit{\addcomma}}
  {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}
  {}
  {}
```

solves the problem.

Complete code (I've also changed `\bibliography` to `\addbibresource`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib, style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
  {\setunit{\addcomma}}
  {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}
  {}
  {}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@MISC{examplea,
  author = {John, Doe},
  title = {MyBook A},
  date = {1991}
}
@MISC{exampleb,
  author = {John, Doe},
  title = {MyBook B},
  date = {1991}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\citet{examplea, exampleb}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am not sure but should the behaviour of biblatex be regarded as a bug?

Comment: @maetra I really don't know. What's the behavior with normal `bibtex`+`natbib`?

Comment: Natbib and bibtex seem to have the same behaviour. Even though, I think it would be better if biblatex would provide some kind of option such as compcitedelim to control the delimiter.