# Biblatex citation: two articles same author, year - years printed in full?

Tags: biblatex

I am citing two articles by the same author in the same year, referenced by the keys `auth00a` and `auth00b`.  With the `authoryear-comp` style, I can use `textcite{auth00a,auth00b}` but this gives me "Author (2000a,b)" in the result.  I would much rather have "Author (2000a, 2000b)"; that is, the years in full.   Is there an easy way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add space between multiple citations in authoryear-style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151578/add-space-between-multiple-citations-in-authoryear-style)

Comment: @Adam, it is similar, but it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @karlkoeller Touché. I guess I wasn't reading closely enough. `:)`

Answer (score 15):

Add the following lines in the preamble (package `xpatch` is needed):

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
  {\setunit{\addcomma}\usebibmacro{cite:extrayear}}
  {\setunit{\compcitedelim}\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
  {}
  {}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
  {\setunit{\addcomma}\usebibmacro{cite:extrayear}}
  {\setunit{\compcitedelim}\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
  {}
  {}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{auth00a,
  author = {Author},
  title = {MyBook A},
  date = {2000}
}
@article{auth00b,
  author = {Author},
  title = {MyBook B},
  date = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{auth00a,auth00b}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That looks like a very comprehensive solution - thank you very much.  Is this sort of fine-tuning described in the Biblatex documentation?

Comment: @Alasdair unfortunately not. I've learned how to do similar things in this site...

Comment: @Alasdair BTW, remember that you can accept (and upvote) the answer if it solves your problem :-)

Comment: Just a quick heads-up: Some of the bibmacros involved here were renamed a while ago. `cite:extrayear` is now `cite:extradate` and `cite:labelyear+extrayear` is `cite:labeldate+extradate`. The patch needs to be changed accordingly to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want this behaviour for all `\...cite` commands and not just `\textcite` (the question only mentions the `\textcite` output), you can try the following. The idea relies on the fact that in order to suppress the year and print only the extradate letter, `biblatex` needs to remember the last year. If we make `biblatex` forget the last year, the year will never be omitted.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{\global\undef\cbx@lastyear}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}

ipsum \autocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:c}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Knuth 1986a, 1986b) ipsum (Knuth 1984, 1986b)]

Answer (score 0):

So, about the `xpatch` solution.
After Moewe pointed out that we should replace -year by -date in the names of the macros, here is the result. But I'm warning you, this will not work with ext-authoryear-comp, only with authoryear-comp, which really should make Moewe's "3-line solution" (see above) your favorite call.

```
   \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
  {\setunit{\addcomma}\usebibmacro{cite:extradate}}
  {\setunit{\compcitedelim}\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
  {}
  {}

\xpatchbibmacro{cite}
  {\setunit{\addcomma}\usebibmacro{cite:extradate}}
  {\setunit{\compcitedelim}\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
  {}
  {}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{auth00a,
  author = {Author},
  title = {MyBook A},
  date = {2000}
}
@article{auth00b,
  author = {Author},
  title = {MyBook B},
  date = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite[cf.][56]{auth00a,auth00b}

\cite[cf.][56]{auth00a,auth00b}

\parencite[cf.][56]{auth00a,auth00b}
\end{document}
```

[image]