# Customizing citation style for multiple articles by same author in the same year

Tags: biblatex

My problem is similar to the one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156436/biblatex-citation-two-articles-same-author-year-years-printed-in-full). But I am unable to make the solution work for my use case. I need it for parencite, and I am calling biblatex with options from the ones used in the other case. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp,bibstyle=authoryear,hyperref=true,maxcitenames=3,doi=false,url=true,backend=biber,natbib=true,maxbibnames=99,uniquename=false,uniquelist=false,indexing=cite]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{parencite}
  {\setunit{\addcomma}\usebibmacro{cite:extrayear}}
  {\setunit{\compcitedelim}\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
  {}
  {}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{auth00a,
  author = {Author},
  title = {MyBook A},
  date = {2000}
}
@article{auth00b,
  author = {Author},
  title = {MyBook B},
  date = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{auth00a,auth00b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want that for all commands, `\renewbibmacro*{cite:extrayear}{\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}` might be the easiest way to go. But that will not take care of the separator, I will add an answer to ensure it is treated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The `\parencite` command relies on the bibmacro `cite`, and we will have to patch that. As such

```
\xpatchbibmacro{cite}
  {\setunit{\addcomma}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:extrayear}}
  {\setunit{\compcitedelim}\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
  {}
  {}
```

Should suffice.

If you want the same to apply to `\citeyear`, you will also need

```
\xpatchbibmacro{citeyear}
  {\setunit{\addcomma}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:extrayear}}
  {\setunit{\compcitedelim}\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
  {}
  {}
```

One could probably clean up the whole citation command now, since some of its finesse is not needed any more.

It would then look like this

```
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother
```

Of course, as so often, the `xpatch` solution is shorter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp,bibstyle=authoryear,hyperref=true,maxcitenames=3,doi=false,url=true,backend=biber,natbib=true,maxbibnames=99,uniquename=false,uniquelist=false,indexing=cite]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{cite}
  {\setunit{\addcomma}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:extrayear}}
  {\setunit{\compcitedelim}\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
  {}
  {}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}
\end{document}
```

[image]